# Use "Server Certificates" remotely in IIS

Tags: iis, certificate-authority, remote-access

I'm using IIS Manager to remotely manage another IIS server.

When I'm managing the local server, I can select the "Server Certificates" icon under IIS when I select the local server in the list to the left.

However, when I select the remote server in the list, the icon for "Server Certificates" disappears.

Is there a way to get it to show up?

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but why not just connect to the other IIS server and select the Certificates from there?  If nothing else, it would be useful to troubleshoot where the error is (such as if there's a good reason it's not showing up from the remote server, like that one IIS server not having the requisite roles or configurations in place).

Comment: That would be easy if it was possible, but the server is running the server core version of Windows, so no other UI than a command prompt.

And installing the full UI is not an option, also, it should be doable remotely somehow :)

Comment: Might be time to brush up on your CLI skills so you can check the IIS configs from the actual box in question? :)

Comment: I know my CLI pretty well, I have however not been able to find which powershell cmdlet to call to send a domain certificate request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible in IIS 7.x becuase the Server Certificates functionality depends on the certificate store.  Since there is no way to remotely access the certificate store via the IIS Management application the option is not made available when working on a remote server.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why it does not work.